# Adding one item of a single product, changing the quantity of all products in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, shopping-cart

Tried to add two buttons, one to add item(increment the quantity count) and other to delete item(decrements quantity count) to update the quantity parameter. When i click on the add item button of one product, the quantity of all the products is  getting updated. How to make these buttons work independently for each product? 
Below is the code i wrote:

```
 import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import products from './Products';
import {
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableHeader,
    TableHeaderColumn,
    TableRow,
    TableRowColumn, } from 'material-ui/Table';



const style = {
    height: 600,
    width: 900,
    margin: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    display: 'inline-block',
  };


export default class Cart extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={ count:1 }
    }


addOne(id) {                              // addOne one item when button clicked
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {count : prevState.count + 1 }
     });
   }

   removeOne(id) {                              // removeOne one item when button clicked
    this.setState(prevState => {
        if(prevState.count>=1) {
      return { count : prevState.count - 1 }
        }
        else{
            alert('quantity cant be less than zero')
        }
     });
   }

render(){
    return(
        <div> 
            <Paper style={style} zDepth={1} > 
                <div> 
                    <div>
                        <h3> here are the products ! </h3>
                    </div> <hr/>
                    <div>
                                {Products.map(productlist =>(
                                    <Table >
                                        <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false} >
                                            <TableRow>
                                                <TableHeaderColumn></TableHeaderColumn>
                                                <TableHeaderColumn></TableHeaderColumn>
                                                <TableHeaderColumn></TableHeaderColumn>
                                                <TableHeaderColumn></TableHeaderColumn>
                                            </TableRow>
                                        </TableHeader>
                                        <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false} >
                                            <TableRow key={productlist.id}>
                                                <TableRowColumn>{productlist.name}</TableRowColumn>
                                                <TableRowColumn>{productlist.description}</TableRowColumn>
                                                <TableRowColumn>{productlist.description}</TableRowColumn>
                                                <TableRowColumn>Price per each item:<br/> {productlist.price}</TableRowColumn>
                                                <TableRowColumn>
                                                <input  type='button' onClick={this.addOne.bind(this,productlist.id)} value='add an item'/>
                                                <input  type='button' onClick={this.removeOne.bind(this,productlist.id)} value='remove an item'/>
                                                    <br/> <span> quantity:  {this.state.count}  </span> 
                                                </TableRowColumn>
                                            </TableRow>
                                        </TableBody>
                                    </Table>
                                ))}

                            </div>
                            <div> 
                                <p> Total price: </p>
                    </div>

                 </div>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Below is the sample Product.js code:

```
    let Products=[
    {
        id:1, name:"Fastrack Women's Watch", 
        description:"Analog Pink Dial Women's Watch - 6150SM04",
        price:2500
    },
    {
        id:2, name:"Fastrack Women's Watch", 
        description:"Analog Pink Dial Women's Watch - 6150SM04",
        price:2100
    },
    {
        id:3, name:"Fastrack Women's Watch", 
        description:"Analog Pink Dial Women's Watch - 6150SM04",
        price:1800
    },

];

export default Products;
```

Comment: you know that's pointless, right? your count is the length of `products` so if you keep that in your state, push to the array or slice, set state and the render will take care of it. show `{state.products.length}` for number records.

Comment: what do u want me to push to the array?can you please be even more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you rethink the design of your program abit. In my opinion you should move the individual product to its own component and then that would have a state too. So, remove the state from the Cart and create a component and name it as Product. This Product component would be a child component of Cart. If you need to update something in Cart from Product then you could use callback.

So something like

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <..>
            {products.map(product => {
                 // New shiny component with state
                 return <Product {...props} />
             })}
        <..>
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. tried it the way you mentioned. It neither throws any error nor it displays anything on the webpage.

Comment: I forgot the return statement. Trying doing it like 
{
    return <Product {...props} />
}

Comment: i wrapped the whole thing in return() itself. I moved the onclick methods, and table that i used to display the data to another component. I rendered that component in the Cart component following the way you mentioned.

Comment: Ya, that too would be needed. You have to return from render function too.

Comment: It worked! Thanks !Though i wrote everything in return(), why we need to return the Product component while mapping?

Comment: Glad that I can help you. 

Map has in its definition that it needs to return the value to the new array. You can find more details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Also, you could accept and upvote the answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Accepted it but dont have enough reputations to upvote

Comment: Hi, I tried to add a method to calculate subtotal(price*quantity) for each product. Im able to print to console but not able to figure how to display it on the page. Also, how can i calculate the total(sum of all subtotals).  can you pls help me with this? I have updated your answer with my code, so that you can check it.

Comment: I recommend you creating a new question as its a different problem and also your question gets more visibility. You can add the link to your question here and I could look into it when I have some time.

Comment: Hi. Here is the link to the new question i asked: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566117/unable-to-get-the-total-of-all-the-products-in-the-cart-in-reactjs